# surprising c# execution times, IL, vs AOT, vs WASM (and c and JS too)

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly

Writing a WASM app that needs some fast compute power (signal processing). Trying to decide if I should use c, JS or c# (I already have c# library that I wrote). So I decided to do CPU intense workload and compare. Will use Sieve of E

First to get a baseline I decided to just do on desktop, not WASM.

So here is c# code I used.

```
public static class App {
    static char[] prime = new char[100000];
    public static int SieveOfEratosthenes(int n) {

        Array.Fill<char>(prime, (char)1);


        for (int p = 2; p * p <= n; p++) {
            // If prime[p] is not changed,
            // then it is a prime
            if (prime[p] == 1) {
                // Update all multiples of p
                for (int i = p * p; i <= n; i += p)
                    prime[i] = (char)0;
            }
        }
        int count = 0;
        // Print all prime numbers
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            if (prime[i] == 1)
                count++;
        }
        return count;


    }
    public static void Run() {

        for (int i = 2; i < 99999; i++) {
            SieveOfEratosthenes(i);
        }
        // Driver Code

    }
    static void Main() {
        var start = DateTime.Now;
        Run();
        var end = DateTime.Now;
        var time = (end - start).TotalMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine(time);

    }
}
```

- Run release build using regular compiled output = ~14 seconds
- Run crossgen2 x64 release output = ~22 seconds (!)
- run crossgen2 x86 release output = ~12 seconds

Crossgen2 done by doing 'publish' in vs2022 and choose specific platform

I am surprised to see that the x64 is so slow. Any thoughts?

Another baseline I did was the same calculation in c and JS (still on desktop)

- run c equivalent code = ~4 seconds
- JS code in node = ~26 seconds

JS code

```
prime = new Uint8Array(100000);
function sieveOfEratosthenes(n)
{
     prime.fill(1);
    for (p = 2; p * p <= n; p++)
    {
        // If prime[p] is not changed, then it is a
        // prime
        if (prime[p] == 1)
        {
            // Update all multiples of p
            for (i = p * p; i <= n; i += p)
                prime[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    var count = 0;
    // Print all prime numbers

    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (prime[i] == 1)
           count++;
    }
    return count;
}
globalThis.sieve = () => {
    // Driver Code
    var n = 30;
    console.time("sieve");
    for (var j = 3; j < 99999; j++) {
        var count = sieveOfEratosthenes(j);
        //console.log(count);
    }
    console.timeEnd("sieve");
}
globalThis.sieve();
```

C code

```
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int SieveOfEratosthenes(int n)
{

   static   char prime[100000];
    memset(prime, 1, sizeof(prime));

    for (int p = 2; p * p <= n; p++)
    {
        // If prime[p] is not changed,
        // then it is a prime
        if (prime[p] == 1)
        {

            for (int i = p * p; i <= n; i += p)
                prime[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    int count = 0;
    // Print all prime numbers
    for (int p = 2; p <= n; p++)
        if (prime[p])
            count++;
    return count;

}

// Driver Code
int sieve()
{
    int start = time(NULL);
    for (int i = 3; i < 99999;i++)
    {

        int count = SieveOfEratosthenes(i);
       // printf("%d ", i/count);
    }
    int end = time(NULL);
   // printf("time=%d", end - start);
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    sieve();
}
```

Second surprise is how much slower c# is that C. I didnt expect that much of a hit. Nor did I expect the JS version to give c# such a close race.

FYI, I WASMd the C code and the c# code and ran in Blazor App

- c code ~4 seconds
- JS code ~27 secs (as expected)
- c# code 26 minutes !!
- c# code AOT ~26 seconds

Lessons

- C# blazor not AOT is horrifically slow
- AOT c# ~= JS
- C is best (a surprise that its so much faster)

Anybody think I messed anything up getting these numbers, as I said there are a few surprises in there.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Julia my question is 'did I miss something in my test, can the code I used to test things be improved to make it a fairer comparison', I wondered about the clear of 100000 bytes

Comment: @Julia can anybody explain the slowness of the x64 code?

Comment: First, your code doesn't work. Second, without the equivalent code in the various languages we can't tell you why it didn't work as well as that code. But for one glaring problem, you're clearing the `primes` array every time you call your sieve method, and you're counting 'primes' every call too, but then doing nothing with it. Perhaps this would be better on CodeReview.

Comment: @Corey Yes, I didnt post the main wrapper for the c# code, will add. Yes, the intent was to count the primes up to 3 then up to 4, then up to 5,.....99999 I will post the C and JS

Comment: @Corey Not really codereview material either, I know its a bit of a mismatch for SO too, but was curious if anybody wanted to point anything glaring out

Comment: I think problem with c# is that loops aren't bound-check-elimination friendly and JIT inserts bound check before every array access. You can try to use unsafe code or use managed pointers with [GetArrayDataReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.getarraydatareference?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @JL0PD ah yes, big difference between c# and c, will try unsafe. The x64 one really gets me though

Comment: Also `prime` array should be `bool[]`. C doesn't have support for bools and therefore chars are used. In C `char` is 1 byte, in C# `char` is 2 bytes

Comment: @JL0PD I had bool originally but felt that the cost of bit twiddling was an overhead (have to read byte, do bit op, write back, vs straight write for char). Will change to byte, forgot that char is 2 bytes. Looked array.fill, it has fast path for 1 byte objects

Comment: @JL0PD changing char to byte results in something slightly slower running  in JIT mode , another surpise. Change to bool is about the same as byte. Implication, the cost of managing those flags is not a huge part of the overall speed